# Java Method with generic class as argument

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, arguments

It is possible write a method in java with generic class with argumet??

example:

```
public void Transfer (class c){
    class.Search();
}
```

Comment: Yes you can.. You've got the syntax wrong though :)

Comment: Your question is correct, the answer is "yes". But your example is syntactically incorrect and completely confusing.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers. How can i write a correct method???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would need to do something like so:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public void Transfer(T c) {
        c.Search();
    }
}
```

Since you seem to want to invoke a specific method, you might want to define an interface which provides the methods you are after, and bind the generic constraint with it:

```
public interface MyInt {
    void Search();
}

....
public class Foo<T extends MyInt> {
    public void Transfer(T c) {
        c.Search();
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
public class Foo {
    public void Transfer(MyInt c) {
        c.Search();
    }
}
```

The last example does away with generics and uses interfaces, which can sometimes yield code which is easier to follow, depending on what you are trying to achieve.